# How avoid helper running each time Meteor.user() changes

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I have the following helper in Meteor:

```
fullname(){
  return Meteor.user().currentName;
},
```

But this helper runs every time `Meteor.user()` changes. I only want it to run when `currentName` of the user changes, not for example just `firstName`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.findOne()` and restrict the keys that are returned:

```
fullname(){
  return Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId(),{fields: {currentName: 1}}).currentName;
},
```